# Mutliple Async operations requiring another async result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

So normally I would do something like:

```
var cars = db.GetCarsAsync();
var dogs = db.GetDogsAsync();
var cats = db.GetCatsAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(cars , dogs , cats);
```

Simple enough, but now how do I make sure I maximize my async ability with dependencies:

```
var vet = await db.GetVetAsync(id);

var validDogTypeIds = vet.DogTypes.Select(d => d.Id).ToList();
var validCatTypeIds = vet.CatTypes.Select(d => d.Id).ToList();

var cars = db.GetCarsAsync();
var dogs = db.GetDogsAsync(validDogTypeIds);
var cats = db.GetCatsAsync(validCatTypeIds);

await Task.WhenAll(cars , dogs , cats);
```

Because the operations require the vet to finish, all database operations are on hold, not just the ones requiring a result.

(This is an example, please ignore the fact that simple relationships would solve this problem).

Comment: A single EF context can only support one query at a time. Are you willing to have multiple contexts/connections?

Comment: @StephenCleary Thats a grey area.  It can only execute a single query at a time, but using [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz(v=vs.110).aspx) with EF allows a single connection to load muliple object pseudo-simultaniously.

Comment: I think I'm not clear what you're asking, but are you looking for `ContinueWith`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Interesting! If you're sure it will work, AntP's answer looks good to me.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, his answer does look good, just need him to undelete it! :)

Comment: @AntP Undelete your answer!  It's good.

Comment: Done - EF isn't my thing and after reading the comments I thought I'd missed the point :)

Comment: @StephenCleary I should make it clear that, *yes* I am using multiple `DbContext`.

Comment: @StephenCleary [Here is the follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869245/async-calling-with-multiple-contexts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the "vet" task from blocking the "car" task simply by instantiating both tasks (which - in an `async` context - will also start them) before you await either of them:

```
var vetTask = db.GetVetAsync(id);
var carTask = db.GetCarsAsync();

var vet = await vetTask;
var validDogTypeIds = vet.DogTypes.Select(d => d.Id).ToList();
var validCatTypeIds = vet.CatTypes.Select(d => d.Id).ToList();

var dogs = db.GetDogsAsync(validDogTypeIds);
var cats = db.GetCatsAsync(validCatTypeIds);

await Task.WhenAll(carTask , dogs , cats);
```

`car` and `vetTask` now run concurrently but `vetTask` is awaited before `dogs` and `cats` are started.